# Binding property in class in another class in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I made a simple game, where two players take turns. Sometimes, you can take 2 or more turns. Everything works fine, except I want to show how many turns each player did via binding.

I have page gamePage, class Game and Class Player:

page:

```
public partial class gamePage : Page
{
    private Game game;

    // konstruktor
    public gamePage(string strPlayer1, string strPlayer2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Hrac player1= new Hrac(strPlayer1, 'R');
        Hrac player2= new Hrac(strPlayer2, 'B');
        this.game = new Game(player1, player2, width, height);
        // binding
        DataContext = game;
        // etc...
    }
    // here is: mouse click - game.MakeAMove();
}
```

Game:

```
class Game : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // binding
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // players
    public Player player1;
    public Player player2;
    private Player activePlayer;
}
// konstruktor
public Game(Player player1, Player player2, int width, int height)
{
    // init of players
    this.player1 = player1;
    this.player2 = player2;
    this.activePlayer = player1;
}
public void MakeAMove()
{
    activePlayer.Rounds++;
    makeAChange("player1");
}
// binding - dle itNetwork
protected void makeAChange(string name)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

Player:

```
class Player : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // binding
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int rounds;
    public int Rounds {
        get { return rounds; }
        set
        {
            rounds = value;
            // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
            OnPropertyChanged("Rounds");
        }
    }
    public char Color { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Hrac(string name, char color)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Color = color;

        Rounds = 0;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }

    // binding - via MSDN
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Name="tbPlayer1Rounds" Text="{Binding player1.Rounds}" />
```

Basicly players take turns, when they click, the move will happen and activePlayer will have one more turn (player1.Rounds), then players will swap and so on...
As you can see, I have tried a lots of things. First make a eventhandler in a game, then in a player itself. Made them public for sure. Nothing. The binding doesn't work. If I have property in Game called for example:`int allRounds` and in `MakeAMove()` I would increment that property + bind it to the textBlock, it works! But when I need to **bind property in class which is in another class** - I don't know what to do, I didn't find anything. Am I doing something wrong?

PS: Of course there is more code! It isn't that I don't want you to know what am I doing, it is just useless for binding and I don't want you to distract from the problem.

Edit: typos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `player1` a property instead of a field. The `Binding` can follow a path of properties but not fields.

```
public Player player1{ get; set; }
```

However, you may want to change the spelling of the name now that it is a property...

Comment: I think I have tried that, but thanks. I will try it again (I think I didn't have a eventHandler in player that time).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as @wkl said, making players property instead of field is a solution. I have tried that in property `Rounds` in class `Player` etc... but make this:

```
public Player Player1 { get; set; }
public Player Player2 { get; set; }
```

didn't occur in my mind. Ofc doing that for `player2` will make it happen for both players.

Thanks!

edit: I don't need `eventHandler` in class `Player` now.